# Yolov8 on Raspberry Pi model 4B 64 bit OS

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, raspberry-pi4, yolov8

I am trying to run a yolov8 model on my Raspberry Pi and have installed ultralytics using pip3 install ultralytics command. But whenever I try to import YOLO in Thonny using from ultralytics import YOLO my terminal just outputs Process ended with exit code -4. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("best.pt") #my trained yolov8 model
model.predict(source = 0, show = True)
```

> Process ended with exit code -4

Answer (score 0):

It's the latest version of Torch that is the problem. You can fix it by installing version `1.12.0` instead.

```
pip3 install torch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 torchaudio==0.12.0
```